# Does metallic bond increase with the increase of atoms?

Tags: solid-state-physics, metals

So, metallic bond doesn't form between two atoms, it forms when there are a large number of atoms.

However, the establishment of metallic bond was statistical, thus there might be a time where metallic bond was weak when sufficient but not enough atoms were presented.

Thus, would a pack of MN atoms has stronger metallic bond than a pack of N atoms? How much stronger would it be?

Comment: Metallic nanoparticles are metallic even when pretty darn small. Now, a small particle will have lower total binding energy because of the surface area to volume ratio. Now, just what are you really asking with respect to 'statistical' development of metallic bonds?

Answer (score 1):

Bond forces play a role in whether a material is stiff or flexible. Bond energies play a role in the melting temperature of the material.

Let us first focus on that sense that you are probably asking about bond energies. You should then ask whether we can determine a correlation of melting temperature with number of atoms in a metal cluster. This might lead to [this reference](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-physchem-032210-103454) ([pdf](https://nano.lab.indiana.edu/pubs/2011/Aguado%20and%20Jarrold%20-%202011%20AnnuRevPhysChem%20-%20Melting%20and%20Freezing%20of%20Metal%20Clusters.pdf)) or [the reference](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpcc.7b02768?src=recsys) or others found by a search on "melting point of metal cluster as a function of temperature".

Should you truly want to know about forces rather than energies, you would want to study the cases for how electron withdrawal from an atom affects the strength (force) of its bond with other atoms. You may also find some strong fundamental hints in studies of simple systems [such as this](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-2860(93)87044-A) on the relationships to bond force constant and electronegativity.